# Undefined Index: name in php and unlink error

Tags: php, undefined-index

**//deleteimage.php file**

```
<form action="dbdeleteimg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="sub">
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rwtp");
   $sql="select * from image ";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       $name=$row[0];
    ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $name;?>" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" ><?php echo $name;?>
   </option>
    <?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

The above file is the code to take code from the database and display it, upon selection of the particular option that value should be sent to the other file that is " dbdeleteimg.php "

**//dbdeleteimg.php**

```
<?php
   $con =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rwtp");
   if(!$con){
      die("connection error");
   }
   $name=$sub=$type="";
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $name = $_POST["name"];
       $type=$_POST["sub"];
   }
   $sql="select * from image where name='$name'";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $uploa=$row[3].$row[2];
   unlink($uploa);
   $sql="delete from image where name='$name'";
   if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){     
    //header('Location: option.php');
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3JEo.png)
Now the above code is used to delete the image from the server and database. But after executing those files I'm getting an error

> undefined index :name as shown in the image
>
> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\RWTP\dbdeleteimg.php on line 8
>
> Warning: unlink(): Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\RWTP\dbdeleteimg.php on line 15

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPuFA.png)

Comment: Your select has name `sub`. And `<input>` with name `name` is not present on the form.

Comment: what is $_POST["name"]

Comment: there is no `name` attribute for an `option` element - is that the `name` you are expecting in `dbdeleteimg.php`?

Comment: yes, I want that name to go in the dbdeleteimg.php.

Comment: The name you want to use surely is the value of the option element selected - which will be under the name `sub`. Like I say, an `option` element does not have a `name` attribute - even if it did that would not show in the POST array

Comment: Thank you very much. your answer worked.

Comment: it looks to me from the code in `deleteimage.php` that you ARE sending the `name` of the image in `$_POST['sub']`